# How to get rootfs build timestamp at runtime?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

For version identification purposes, I want to be able to retrieve a timestamp indicating when the root filesystem image was built. It needs to be retrievable on the board itself at runtime.

I'm using The Ångström Distribution, branch angstrom-v2013.12-yocto1.5, which uses OpenEmbedded for building the rootfs (root filesystem).

The kernel is built separately for this board, so I can't use `uname -v` for this purpose since that just reads out the kernel build timestamp, not the rootfs build timestamp.

Does a rootfs build timestamp get added to the rootfs image some place where it can be retrieved at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> BitBake makes it easy to use Python code in variable expansion with
>   the following syntax:
>
> `VARIABLE = "${@python-command}"`
>
> This gives huge flexibility to the user, as can be seen in the following example:
>
> `DATE = "${@time.strftime('%Y%m%d',time.gmtime())}"`
>
> This results in the
>   DATE variable containing today's date.

When an Image is build, there is a time stamp that stored in /etc/timestamp, [Example HERE](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/image.bbclass?h=pinky)

```
rootfs_update_timestamp () {
date "+%m%d%H%M%Y" >${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/timestamp 
}
```

You could take a look at this recipe that implement the days and time and put a file into the rootfs

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "hio-version"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PR = "r0"

DEPENDS = "core-image-minimal"
SRC_URI = "file://version "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "installed-vs-shipped"
FILES_${PN} += " /"

do_install() {
             echo "------------------------"
         echo "------------------------"

        #version
            #echo hio-board-dl-v1.00 > ${WORKDIR}/version
        #date >> ${WORKDIR}/version
            #install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/version ${D}/       
        date_version_1=hio-board-dl-
        date_version_2=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        date_version_3=-R1.00

        echo $date_version_1$date_version_2$date_version_3 > ${WORKDIR}/version
        install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/version ${D}/
}
```

Comment: I thought maybe there would be a built-in solution that I could just utilize, but since my system modifies /etc/timestamp at boot-time, apparently there isn't. I will use your solution and just create my own timestamp file on the rootfs image at build-time via bitbake/python.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by default /etc/timestamp contains the rootfs build time.

Comment: Yeah I thought that would be the case with my system also, but instead /etc/timestamp gets updated every time the system boots. Since I'm using Angstrom with Systemd, maybe this script is the cause: https://github.com/Angstrom-distribution/meta-angstrom/blob/master/recipes-core/systemd/timestamp-service/load-timestamp.sh